# Microsoft Graph API on OneDrive returning error on retrieving children

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I have authenticated to OneDrive and am trying to query it using the Microsoft graph API.  I tried the documented query:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children

However, this returns an HTTP 500 with a JSON body that includes:

```
...
"code": "InternalServerError",
"message": "Unsupported extension property type.",
...
```

Some other queries such as /drive/root and /drive/root:/Documents work fine, but I can't get children to list.

Comment: Could you provide request-id and timestamp returned by a failing call?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this url to make it work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We've identified an issue with such requests for personal Microsoft accounts (LiveId). It has been corrected and you should no longer see such failures.